# How can i create a 3d model from a given two points?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to draw a line between two points and then rotate or more to convert it to a 3d. Like making a building. If it's a cube or cylinder.

Draw a line i mean not to draw it and display the line or maybe i should draw it and show it but by the logic i mean to draw a line between two given points and then to make it 3d.

I tried this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MakeTwoPoints3D : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 pA;
    public Vector3 pB;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // Assuming this is run on a unit cube.
        Vector3 between = pB - pA;
        float distance = between.magnitude;
        transform.localScale.x = distance;
        transform.position = pA + (between / 2.0);
        transform.LookAt(pB);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

But getting errors on the line:

```
transform.localScale.x = distance;
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1612  Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.localScale' because it is not a variable   MakeTwoPoints3D.cs  15  Active

And on the line:

```
transform.position = pA + (between / 2.0);
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0019  Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'double'   MakeTwoPoints3D.cs  16  Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> transform.localScale.x = distance;

You need to create new `Vector3` from `distance` variable then assign it to `transform.localScale`.

```
transform.localScale = new Vector3(distance, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
```

> transform.position = pA + (between / 2.0);

Simply add `f` after the `2.0` to make it float. Without the `f`, `2.0` becomes `double` type.

```
transform.position = pA + (between / 2.0f);
```

See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_divide.html). The division overload method takes `float` not `double`. Looking at your other Unity question, you need to understand basic Unity Vector arithmetic. See [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/vector-maths) and [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).